# How can I open toggleterm in my current working directory?

Tags: neovim

I have started to use neovim recently and installed toggleterm plugin for a terminal. When ever I am in a project and try to open the terminal it starts on my home directory rather than the current working directory of the project.
For example: Suppose I am currently on a project which is at ~/projects/new-project/news-app and when ever I start toggle term the terminal's location is at ~/.
What can I do to make it open on current project directory (~/projects/new-project/news-app).

Operating system: WSL2 Ubunutu22.04
Neovim version: 0.6.1

I have tried enabling autochdir = true in toggleTerm.lua file and also tried adding autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h to my init.vim config file but this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of a session where toggleterm will open in the current directory:

Within a terminal window, before starting nvim, and within the project directory from a terminal prompt enter:

export CDPATH=.,**

Then within the project directory open your file with nvim

In nvim issue the command :lcd %:h BEFORE typing Ctl-\

Ctl-\ should now open ToggleTerm in the current directory

Details:

export CDPATH=.,** assigns the current directory and all subdirectories to the environment variable CDPATH

:lcd %:h should now find the current directory in cdpath within nvim.

If this works, then add export CDPATH=.,** to your session rc file; for example ~/.bashrc, or /etc/profile.d/custom.sh, or such...

Just a note about the terminals. The reason :lcd %:h must be issued prior to the first Ctl-\ is that once a terminal instance is opened it will use the directory reference available at the time of creation. Opening the terminal using Ctl-\ prior to giving the :lcd %:h command will use the available directory, i.e. ~/. Any further attempts to use Ctl-\ will just open the same terminal which uses this directory. This terminal instance will need to be closed using 'exit' at the toggled terminal prompt. Then giving the command :lcd %:h and THEN Ctl-\ will create a new terminal instance but this time the available directory will be the current working directory.

To explore this further try this:
Open your project file and hit Ctl-\ . This will create a terminal using the default directory, likely ~/. Now hit Ctl-\ to get back to the code buffer. Next type :lcd %:h and then 2Ctl-\ . Another terminal will open but this time it will be in the directory of your project file. Hitting Ctl-\ will once again bring back the code buffer. Now type 1Ctl-\ and the first terminal with the ~/ directory will appear. Toggle back and type 2Ctl-\ and the second terminal will appear, once again with the project directory.

Let me know if this is what your were requesting.